# Shell scripting output

Tags: bash

What will be the output of the following script?

```
#!/in/bash

secondLoop="A B C D E F G"
counter=0

for a in 6 7 8 9
do
for b in "$secondLoop"
do
let "counter+=1"
 done
done
echo "This script has $counter iterations"​
```

Options:

1. This script has 28 iterations.
2. This script has 21 iterations.
3. This script has 4 iterations.
4. This script has 0 iterations.

Comment: Why don't you run it and see?

Comment: I don't have linux on my machine.

Comment: You don't need Linux on your machine. Online demo: https://ideone.com/bBNg2h (4 iterations)

Comment: The _code_ posted, as is, will fail with `-bash: ...: /in/bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

It should be 4 iterations, because there are quotes in

```
for b in "$secondLoop"
```

so that the variable is expanded to a single value (that included spaces).